# different increment in range in for-loop pandas

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have a loop code as below:

```
min = 1
max = 300
inc = 10

for j in range (min,max+inc,inc):
    print(j)
```

The increment is 10 from `min` until `max`. Is there any way that I can make the increment change on certain range, for example from range `1-100` the increment is `10`, `101-200` the increment is `20` and `201-300` the increment is `30`?

Comment: Can you provide the expected values around 100, 200 and 300, so we can understand how to handle the edge cases?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `for` loop you can use a `while` loop:

```
min = 1
max = 300
inc = 10

while min <= max+inc:
    print(min)

    if 100 < min <= 200: #define your increment-conditions here
        inc = 20
    elif 200 < min <= 300:
        inc = 30

    min += inc
```

output:

```
1
11
21
31
41
51
61
71
81
91
101
121
141
161
181
201
231
261
291
321
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a generator to generates values, can be used in for-loop, or just convert it into a list

```
# pip install range_key_dict
from range_key_dict import RangeKeyDict


def value_generator(min_value, max_value):
    inc_dict = RangeKeyDict({
        (1, 100): 10,
        (100, 200): 20,
        (200, 300): 30,
    })
    start = min_value
    while start <= max_value:
        inc = inc_dict.get(start, None)
        if inc is None:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            start += inc
            yield start


for j in value_generator(1, 300):
    print(j)

# [11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91, 101, 121, 141, 161, 181, 201, 231, 261, 291, 321]
print(list(value_generator(1, 300)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A general solution might be:

```
incs = [10,20,30]
pos = [101,201,301]
m = 1
for i in range(len(pos)):
    for j in range(m,pos[i],incs[i]):
            print(j)
            m = pos[i]
```

- you can edit the increment values, and the positions that the new value is relevant
- last element of the positions array is the stop condition